# how to add sqldatasource to gridview which is having data without override?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to .Net application development. I'm working on a project using MS Access.
In my application I have one Gridview with unbound data. I have one SQL Datasource which I bind to Gridview dynamically. When I bind that SQL Datasource to the Gridview the existing data is overridden. Instead of overriding I want to append the rows to the existing rows in Gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Best fix would be not to use `SqlDataSource` and get data from db, merge it with existing and bind it to grid.

Answer (score 1):

That was doing the right thing; It definitely overrides the previous data. In that case, you need to create a dataset and append the newly fetched table data to the existing table in the dataset.. :)

Answer (score 1):

### You can't.

`Gridview` can have only one datasource at time. Every time you try to bind another datasource, it always overrides the existing one.

One of the best option is to use [`JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) if these datasource are in same database.

Check also:

- [ASP.NET tips: Display resultset from Multiple DataTable](http://msmvps.com/blogs/shahed/archive/2009/02/09/asp-net-tips-display-resultset-from-multiple-datatable.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

create a view with multiple data datable
a sample code is below

```
jv = New JoinView(ds.Tables!Ord, _
     "OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,CustOrd.CompanyName Company,CustOrd.ContactName Contact,CustOrd.ContactTitle Position,EmpOrd.FirstName,EmpOrd.LastName", _
     "EmployeeID<5", "OrderDate")
DataGrid1.DataMember = ""
DataGrid1.DataSource = jv
```

for more info go through

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;325682